# How to do a user initiated precision location using CoreLocation?

Tags: ios, ios7, core-location, cllocationmanager

Here's my code (the implementing class has the CLCoreLocationManagerDelegate protocol declared):

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    NSLog(@"locations %@", locations);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    NSLog(@"auth status: %u", status);
}

- (void)noteLocation {
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] == NO)
    {
        NSLog(@"rejected");
        return;
    };
    CLLocationManager* manager = [CLLocationManager new];
    manager.delegate = self;
    manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    [manager startUpdatingLocation];
```

}

Running the `noteLocation` method, my app briefly opens the *"thisApp" Would Like to Use your Current Location* prompt. But it immediately closes. I don't get to answer either way. And the delegate methods never fire.

I was just trying to get this far. But there's a larger architecture question at stake too. My app has a *note current location* feature for items it catalogs, so the user can tag his current location as the location of that item. Unless they select that option, I don't need (or want) to waste the battery running the GPS. But when they do, I want as precise as possible value. My thought was to run it at maximum accuracy, wait for a couple of updates (maybe make sure the value is settling), and then record that final value. Is there a better recipe for doing this?

**UPDATE**

The prompt was disappearing because I needed to store the LocationManager instance somewhere where it wouldn't get garbage collected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`, which provides best possible accuracy. Unless you are trying to get current location for a user or object that is in motion, you don't have to wait much for location updates.

CLLocation contains two properties - `horizontalAccuracy` and `verticalAccuracy`. You can measure your program's accuracy by performing some test and displaying the values of these properties.

Comment: Any idea why when I run that code (the `noteLocation` method) at a button press, the allow dialog opens for a second and then disappears, with no interaction?